# Radius of convergence for $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty2^{-n}z^{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What would be the radius of convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{3^n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76173/what-would-be-the-radius-of-convergence-of-sum-limits-n-0-infty-z3n)

How would I find the radius of convergence for $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{-n}z^{n^2}$? Im not sure how to deal with the $z^{n^2}$ term.

I know the ratio test = $\displaystyle\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}|c_n|^\frac{1}{n}$ for $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(z-z_0)^n$, but since I have the $z^{n^2}$ term, how would I deal with it? Is the ratio test I should use now be $\displaystyle\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}|c_{n^2}|^\frac{1}{n^2}$? If so, what exactly would $c_{n^2}$ be?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/76184/6179).

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help Didier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the [root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius) in your OP.
The [$\limsup$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior) in the definition allows you to
ignore the "missing terms" (because they are lesser) in
$$
c_n=\left\{\matrix{
2^{-\sqrt{n}}&&\sqrt{n}\in\mathbb{N}\\
0&&\text{otherwise}}\right.
$$
and reparametrize $n$ at will, i.e. in this case, to avoid vanishing terms; hence we take the $n^2$th rather than the $n$th root:
$$
C \quad=\quad \limsup_{n\to\infty}\,\left(c_n\cdot|z^n|\right)^{1/n}
\quad\underset{n\to n^2}=\quad
|z| \cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1{2^n}\right)^{1/n^2}
\quad=\quad |z|
$$
which converges for $|z|\le r=1$ since
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^{-n/n^2}=1 \,.
$$
If you use the [ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test),
you proceed with the inequality
$$
1 > \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^{-(n+1)}z^{(n+1)^2}}{2^{-n}z^{n^2}}
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{z^{2n+1}}{2}
$$
to still get
$$
r = \lim_{n\to\infty} 2^{-1/(2n+1)}=1 \,.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your help, understood it now!

Comment: One quick question, from $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{z^{2n+1}}{2}$, how did you proceed from there? I can't see what you did after that.

Comment: I replaced $z$ by $r=|z|$ (and took the complex absolute value).

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are right. First, $c_{n^2}$ would be $2^{-n}$. Hence $\lvert c_{n^2}\rvert^{1/n^2}$ is $2^{-1/n}$.

Since this goes to $1$ the convergence radius is $1$ because $\limsup\lvert c_{n^2}\rvert^{1/n^2}=1$.

By the way, for the sequence $\lvert c_{n}\rvert^{1/n}$ the limit does *not* exist.

Comment: Okay thanks, yes the main thing I was not sure was whether $c_{n^2} = 2^{-n}$ or not!

Answer (score 1):

As you say, you cannot find the radius of convergence using the ratio test, since the quotient $c_{n+1}/c_n$ is not defined whenever $c_n=0$. However you can apply the ratio test to the series, forgetting it is a power series, and obtain a condition on $z$ that guarantees convergence. To do this, you must find
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{-(n+1)}|z|^{(n+1)^2}}{2^{-n}|z|^{n^2}}
$$
and impose the condition that it be less than $1$.

You can use the root test in the same fashion, or as you suggest. In that case $c_{n^2}$ is, by definition, the coefficient of $z^{n^2}$.

Comment: Thanks Julian, didnt realise I could use the ratio test to the series and 'forget' it was a power series!

Comment: Working out the limit, what would I do after I reach $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{z^{2n+1}}{2}$?

Comment: First of all: the ratio test is used in series of positive terms, so you must use $|z|$ and not $z$. You find the value of the limit as a function of $|z|$. In this particular case there are three possibilities deppending on the value of $|z|$: $|z|<1$, $|z|=1$ and $|z|>1$. Th series will converge when the limit is $<1$.

Comment: Okay, thanks Julian, most appreciated!